# How to load a REST call through a script tag

Tags: javascript, rest

I understand that this a bit odd of a question but here I go. I am writing an application that will be switching environments (dev, test, prod, etc). I need the base URL for my REST calls to change as I switch environments. Well, our current solution (and I am all ears for better solutions) is a local REST call asking the server what environment I am in and what URL I should be using for my base. The external REST calls are separated from the front end completely.

With the local REST call I could do an ajax call to get the data somewhere in my javascript or I could include the REST call as follows:

```
<script src="/rest/configs"></script>
```

The problem with the above solution is that it returns an object that is not assigned to a variable thus throwing errors. So my over all question is, Can you load a REST call through a script tag straight into a variable and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you do this with a script tag the response of the request ( not AJAX at all ) will be parsed and executed as javascript.

What you could do is to return valid Javascript, rather than JSON object. Something like

```
window.config = {"env":"test"};
```

rather than

```
{"env":"test"}
```

Other option is not to do this with script tag and just write inline javascript with an ajax call. If you use jQuery it would look like :

```
<script>$.get("/rest/configs", function(config) { window.config = config; });</script>
```

This will do the Ajax call and assign it to a global variable config. Of course you should make some adjustments and execute the rest of your javascript after this is executed.

Anyway as a standard, this value is usually hard-coded in the scripts. I would suggest to create a script that is modified for test/dev/production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Can't your rest call just return a Javascript object, like so:

```
var env = "experimental";
```

Your webpage should be able to interpret this as Javascript and the `env` variable should be usable in the rest of your page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/rest/configs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("env: " + env); // prints env: experimental
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```